# Creating MEMORY table with varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I need to create `TEMPORARY` tables for processing (via `JOIN`) a large set of data (1M rows), which have `varchar` columns. If I use `ENGINE=MEMORY`, it will change `varchar` to `char`. Then, the data will not fit into memory (even by increasing `tmp_table_size`/`max_heap_table_size`).

I understand that memory mapping need `char` structure, but is there a workaround to create `TEMPORARY` tables in `MEMORY` using `varchar` to minimise the memory usage?

This is my process:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
(
ArticleID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
Tag varchar(255),
INDEX(Tag),
PRIMARY KEY(ArticleID,Tag)
) ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' IGNORE INTO TABLE temp 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
  (ArticleID,Tag);

// Adding missing tags in tag table
INSERT IGNORE INTO Tags (Tag) SELECT DISTINCT Tag FROM temp;

INSERT INTO TagMap (ArticleID,TagID) 
  SELECT a.ArticleID,b.TagID FROM temp a JOIN Tags b ON a.Tag=b.Tag;
```

In my experience, `InnoDB` has a better performance as compared with `Aria` and `MyISAM`.

Comment: Without [MDEV-19](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19) fixed, I don't see a solution using the `MEMORY` engine. Are you sure that a InnoDB or Aria temporary table won't have the necessary performance? I assume you're avoiding the IO on creation?

Comment: @danblack The performance of InnoDB was much better than Aria and MyISAM (to my surprise). I/O is not my problem per se but the speed. I just create these tables for the data structure of `ArticleID,Tag` to `JOIN` with the tag table to get `TagID`. Therefore, they are short-lived. The bottle-neck is their creation.

Comment: `LOAD DATA ... TERMINATED BY '\n'  (ArticleID,@Tag) SET TagHash = UNHEX(SHA1(@Tag))` and then the `TagHash` can be a `binary(20)` if I calculated that right. Then your memory table would be smaller.  Your real `Tag` table would also need the same indexed hash column. Acceptable?

Comment: @danblack your approach is subtle, but I forgot to mention another step in my procedure. I added to the sample code: I have to `INSERT` possible missing tags before `JOIN`. Sorry for my failure to clarify!

Comment: @danblack of course, your approach is still working if I add another `LOAD DATA` into the tag table.

Comment: It does make it tricker. Add a `latestArticleID` column to `Tags`. Assuming `Tags(Tag)` is a unique key. Than `LOAD DATA REPLACE .. INTO Tags` and use triggers to populate `TagMap`

Answer (score 1):

You will be better off *not* 'normalizing' tags.

```
CREATE TABLE Tags (
    ArticleID int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
    Tag varchar(255),
    INDEX(Tag),
    PRIMARY KEY(ArticleID,Tag)
) ENGINE=innoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

LOAD DATA ... INTO Tags ...;
```

Skip the rest of your steps.

Now simplify the code elsewhere since you don't need to go through `TagMap` to get to a `tag`.

And there is no need for `MEMORY`.  (And possibly no advantage, anyway.)  Nor a SHA1 kludge.

Note that `INDEX(Tag)` will be "covering" when Joining from `Tag` to `ArticleID`.  This is because InnoDB tacks the PK onto the end of each secondary index.

(I did not follow your "missing tags" issue, but it might be simpler now that there is only one new table.)

Example from Comments -- List articles have all of 3 specific tags:

```
SELECT a.*
    FROM ( SELECT articleID FROM Tags
             WHERE tag IN ('foo', 'bar', thing')
             HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
         ) AS t
    JOIN Articles AS a USING(articleID);
```

Comment: A reasonable suggestion, but I cannot denormalise the `tags` table because it is too large (tens of millions of rows) and serves several tag_map tables. My current approach is slow in adding entries but will be faster in reading later on. Surely, by your method, there will be no "missing tags", as there is no `tags` table, and we use tags directly in `tag_map`s.

Comment: @Googlebot - I think I need to see some typical `SELECTs` to better understand your point.

Comment: Are you saying, "There are tags that don't belong to any articles?"

Comment: No, tags always belong to at least one article. "missing tags" refers to the absence of a tag in `Tags` table (when we don't have `TgaID` for a new tag). `SELECT` is simple like `SELECT ArticleID FROM TagMap WHERE TagID IN(1,2,3) GROUP BY ArticleID HAVING COUNT(*)=3`.

Comment: @Googlebot - I added the query for your example.

Comment: My point was that `WHERE TagID IN(1,2,3)` is much faster than `WHERE tag IN ('foo', 'bar', thing')` when the table is 10M+. Not to mention the I/O overhead for a larger table storing `varchar`. In long run, the normalisation compensates by the read performance.

Comment: @Googlebot - Don't forget to add in the time taken to lookup (1,2,3) from the strings.